# Google Plus API - Cannot Handle Token Prior to Certain Date

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I implemented a login functionality using Google Plus API. It was working fine until we moved the deployment timezone. The problem below started appearing from time to time even though the server time has been adjusted properly:

> Cannot handle token prior to 2018-02-01T06:30:07+0000

This was implemented in PHP and using the SDK for Google Plus. Has anyone encountered this before and resolved it properly?

Comment: Where are you hitting this exactly?  What timezone did you move from to

Comment: @DalmTo Mexico City

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me as well. I had to go into my vendor folder that composer generates for me in `vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\AccessToken\Verify.php` and look for a function `getJwtService()` which should look exactly like this

```
    private function getJwtService()
  {
    $jwtClass = 'JWT';
    if (class_exists('\Firebase\JWT\JWT')) {
      $jwtClass = 'Firebase\JWT\JWT';
    }

    if (property_exists($jwtClass, 'leeway')) {
      // adds 1 second to JWT leeway
      // @see https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/827
      $jwtClass::$leeway += 1;
    }

    return new $jwtClass;
  }
```

Then I changed the value of the `$jwtClass::$leeway += 1;` to `$jwtClass::$leeway += 200;` due to my timezone. I was about 2mins 30 seconds behind. Beware this comes with security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer provided by richard4s works well but it's not a good practice to edit files in vendor directory as they are created by composer and would typically be outside your project's Git/Svn repo. The `Google_Client` accepts custom jwt object as a parameter to it's constructor. So here's a proper way to fix this:

```
$jwt = new \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
$jwt::$leeway = 5; // adjust this value

// we explicitly pass jwt object whose leeway is set to 5
$this->client = new \Google_Client(['jwt' => $jwt]);
```

Copied from [this](https://perials.com/login-google-using-php-google-php-client/#fix-for-before-valid-exception) article.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears to occur when the server's clock is a few seconds behind Auth servers clock.  You probably have a slight [skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew) between the clock on the server that mints the tokens and the clock on the server that's validating the token if the iat or nbf is in the future, then the token isn't yet valid.

One solution would be to use a small leeway, like this:

> JWT::$leeway = 5; // Allows a 5 second tolerance on timing checks

see issue [1172](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1172)

Comment: I saw this solution as well but the common concern is that it's a workaround that shouldn't done at all.

Comment: Well the other option would be to fix the server so that it has the correct time.    It needs to be in sync with NTP, however clock skew is a known issue and that is why we have the ability to fix this problem.   I wouldnt call this a workaround.

Comment: Thing is, the server has the correct time already. I'm wondering where  2018-02-01T06:30:07+0000 is coming from.

Comment: I cant really tell you that.   You could try posting an issue up on the github issue form for the library.  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client  or you could download the full source code and debug your way though it.